# ¿Cómo puedo saber la cantidad de ventanas minimizadas y ancladas en la barra de tarea de windows?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, windows, windows10

Buenas, estoy inmerso en un proyecto donde muestro determinada información en un Panel que inserto en la parte inferior derecha de la barra de tareas de Windows. El problema es que solo deseo que se agregue a esa zona si no se ha llenado mucho la barra, para no superponerlo sobre algo que ya exista.

Esto es lo que he logrado hacer.

[image: Resultado]

Lo que está marcado es el panel que cree en la barra de tareas.
He investigado un poco y me he informado que recorriendo todas las ventanas con EnumWindows y comprobando su estado puedo saber las minimizadas pero aún faltarían las que están ancladas. Agregar que lo estoy haciendo en Windows 10. Bienvenida cualquier información adicional que pueda ayudarme a terminar el proyecto. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tengo entendido que las ventanas, aunque estén ancladas, siguen "enumerándose" como ventanas por EnumWindows, igual estoy equivocado pero es lo mismo si están o no ancladas, el anclaje es solo un acceso directo para abrir la ventana.

Otra cosa que debes tener en cuenta, EnumWindows solo te dará información acerca de las aplicaciones Win32 (las que funcionan también en Windows anteriores a Windows 8), las aplicaciones de la tienda no las enumera, igual te sirve mas la función 'FindWindowEx' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500(v=vs.85).aspx